# The site description doesn't mention Japanese in a few important places

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [about page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/about) contains a truncated version of the site description:

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists.

The banner for new visitors has the same omission (on both the main site and the meta site).

[image: Welcome to Q&A about the Stack Exchange site for students, teachers, and linguists — check out the FAQ!]

Comment: Good catch!  Let’s hope that it will be fixed soon.

Comment: We'll take a look.

Comment: @Rebecca: Thanks!  There is a small problem, though.  Please read [my reply](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/145/the-site-description-doesnt-mention-japanese-in-a-few-important-places/207#207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banner for new visitors has been fixed.  The [about page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/about) has been almost fixed, but the period is duplicated:

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language..

Comment: Fixed - thanks!

Comment: @Rebecca: Thanks!